# Applying styles to a <span> inside a "display:flex"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having an issue where I would like to underline text, and/or add additional styles to a  or any other element really inside a flex container. I am having issues: Centering not working the way I want it to work. Adding a span makes a mess. Please read the notes in the code. How do I add additional styles and keep the flex and not make a mess?

```css
#first
{
    height: 527px;
    background: url(img/gbackground.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    font: normal normal 30px/50px Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<!-- I want to put a span around "View Our Services, but it ruins the flexbox,
I want the "View Our services" centered below the top 3 words: "Your Business Online" 
and with some space
on the left, I added some whitespace as a ghetto hack, but how can I add spans
so I can do extra cool things and not disrupt the flex? I also tried adding
a underline to the "-->
<div id="first" class="col">Your Business Online </br> &nbsp;&nbsp;View Our Services</div>

<!-- WTF? -->
<div id="first" class="col">Your Business Online </br> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="space">View Our Services</span></div>
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Provide `flex-direction: column` to the container.

**Changes in Markup :**

- Made `.first` class instead of id for container.
- Removed the break line tag from the second container.

See, if it helps.

```css
.first
{
height: 527px;
background: url(img/gbackground.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
font: normal normal 30px/50px Times, serif;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!-- I want to put a span around "View Our Services, but it ruins the flexbox,
I want the "View Our services" centered below the top 3 words: "Your Business Online" 
and with some space
on the left, I added some whitespace as a ghetto hack, but how can I add spans
so I can do extra cool things and not disrupt the flex? I also tried adding
a underline to the "-->
<div class="first" class="col">Your Business Online </br> &nbsp;&nbsp;View Our Services</div>

<!-- WTF? -->
<div class="first" class="col">Your Business Online  &nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="space">View Our Services</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below. I documented the changes in the source code.

```css
#first
{
height: 527px;
background: url(img/gbackground.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column; /* change from row (default) */
font: normal normal 30px/50px Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<!-- Put a span around 'Your Business Online' also. Remove line break and
non-breaking spaces -->
<div id="first" class="col"><span>Your Business Online</span><span id="space">View Our Services</span></div>
```